# Send custom data to backend with every message?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

How do I sent custom data to my back end with each message the user sends? For example, let's say I want to send the user's local time (using the client's browser to run javascript: `new Date()`) with every message to my back end. How would I do this using Bot Framework Web Chat?

I'm using regular JS and not react.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the following [example in the official docs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/b.piggyback-on-outgoing-activities). Basically you can add a Middleware from which you can "capture" all outgoing activities.

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
        action = window.simpleUpdateIn(
          action,
          ['payload', 'activity', 'channelData', 'email'],
          () => 'johndoe@example.com'
        );
      }

      return next(action);
    });
```

And now all 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY' sent on this bot will now have an email added to the channel data.

Comment: Do you know how to do this using React library? <ReactWebChat directLine={directLine} userID={id} locale='en-US'>